# Render twig template in Sonata-Admin Bulk-Action: You cannot use the "renderView"

Tags: php, dependency-injection, sonata-admin, symfony6

I created a Sonata Admin-Class which I also added a customized Batch-Action:

```
protected function configureBatchActions(array $actions): array
{
    $actions =  parent::configureBatchActions($actions);
    $actions['compareConfig'] = [
        'ask_confirmation' => false,
        'controller' => 'app.config_compare_controller::batchCompareConfigAction'
    ];

    return $actions;
}
```

The service-definition (services.yaml):

```
    app.config_compare_controller:
    class: App\Controller\DatabasesCompareController
    arguments: [ '@service_container' ]
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]
```

Controller (DatabasesCompareController):

```
public function batchCompareConfigAction(ProxyQueryInterface $query, AdminInterface $admin): ?Response {
...
dump($this->container->has('twig')); // => false
    return $this->render('Admin/Databases/config_compare.html.twig', [
        'content' => $content
    ]);
```

Due to the fact, that in another controller twig renders fine the following error-message confuses me:

You cannot use the "renderView" method if the Twig Bundle is not available. Try running "composer require symfony/twig-bundle" (in vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/AbstractController.php)

Symfony: 6.0.11
Sonata-Admin: 4.17.0

What can I do to render my output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself:
You have to add the twig-Enviroment as an argument.

```
   app.config_compare_controller:
        class: App\Controller\DatabasesCompareController
        arguments: [ '@twig' ]
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]
```